# Count on ranges

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook where sheet1 shows a date and below that categories. sheet2 then shows the same date but wants a total of all the subcategories from sheet1.  So sheet1 would have an `X` in it and sheet2 would need a count of all the `X` for the specified.

Is there a combination of INDEX/MATCH or INDEX/MATCH/MATCH I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes there is. Please provide specific example of your data structure and also what formula you have tried so far.

Comment: can you give an example?  You could use the countif can't you?

Comment: @ergonaut - yes I could use CountIF() but I can't figure out how to match on 3 items.  For example the value on the left, the daterange at the top as well as all sub-options under the date?

Comment: Please do what @nbayly suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIFS.

I presume you have something like this, and if so, here is the solution: (sheet1 on the right, sheet2 on the left)

[Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U5vq.png)

If not, you'll need to provide an example of what you mean.